# Heroku не скачивает нужные библиотеки

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, telebot

Залил на heroku телеграм бота идентичный тому, что лежит на это [GitHub](https://github.com/Alexitmisty/raspis8182/blob/master/raspisanie.py). При запуске на локалке всё работает правильно, однако при запуске с сервера выдаётся следующая ошибка в логах:

```
2019-09-04T19:35:39.622608+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-09-04T19:35:39.622629+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "raspisanie.py", line 3, in <module>
2019-09-04T19:35:39.622761+00:00 app[worker.1]: from telebot import types
2019-09-04T19:35:39.622785+00:00 app[worker.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'types'
```

Понятное дело, что проблема начинается уже с загрузки библиотеки

Сам код выглядит так:

```py
import telebot
import datetime
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('722998100:AAEOn6OK74dP1uMX8a_JjeEsPmVD7tsoD68')
keyboard1=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
keyboard1.row('/start','Hello')
keyboard2=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
keyboard2.row('Понедельник',"Вторник")
```

Если убирать уточнение со скачкой types и добавлять в две строчки Telebot для получения
`keyboard1=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)`
То будет выдавать ошибку, что у Telebot нет аттрибута types.
В requirements.txt прописано:

```
telebot
datetime
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Покажите `print(telebot)` и `import os; print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(telebot.__file__)))`

Comment: @andreymal Что именно? Именно результат,  если ввести это в Python IDLE?
Если да, то оно выдает следующее:
`>>> import os
>>> import telebot
>>> print(telebot)
<module 'telebot' from 'C:\\Users\\4N71c\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\telebot\\__init__.py'>
>>> print(os.listdir(os.path.dirname(telebot.__file__)))
['__init__.py', '__pycache__']
>>> `

Comment: @andreymal
` <module 'telebot' from '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py'>
app[worker.1]: ['__pycache__', '__init__.py']
app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[worker.1]: File "raspisanie.py", line 8, in <module>
app[worker.1]: keyboard1=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'types' is not defined`

Comment: А, так вы ж неправильный telebot установили, нужно ставить pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: @andreymal Странно, вроде работал по примерам и там прописывалось именно telebot. Получается нужно заменить на 'import pyTelegramBotAPI'?
Или только в requirements.txt дополнительно прописать?

Comment: Только в requirements.txt

Comment: Не дополнительно, а вместо. Неправильный telebot нужно удалить

Comment: @andreymal
Спасибо, заработало. А как именно стало понятно, что надо было прописать  pyTelegramBotAPI, а не Telebot?

Comment: Из документации telebot ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal А где её найти можно?

Comment: @andreymal И напиши в ответе, что надо прописывать в requirements.txt именно pyTelegramBotAPI. ))))

Comment: Ну например по первой ссылке в гугле по запросу telebot?) https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: @andreymal
Окей, я думал, это немного не то))) 
Добавь ответ.